# Setting user and password for Proxy in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, proxy

Is there a way to configure Ubuntu proxy with a script so that web browser wont ask for username/password?

I'm trying to change dynamically my proxy and I would like my web browser to follow my Ubuntu configuration. -> Chrome and Firefox keep asking for authentication.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host '******'$1
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port '******'

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user '*****'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password '*****'

gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your proxy information to `apt.conf` located in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

In `apt.conf` add the following:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://<user_name>:<password>@<proxy address>:<port>";`